# angular 6 news ticker ui using an array, css animation

Tags: css, angular, css-animations, angular-animations

This is what I have. [stackbitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rexlwo) Change the position of the array element.

I want to move items to top with an animation like in this [example.](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Flexible-jQuery-Vertical-News-Ticker-Plugin-Advanced-News-Ticker/) 
problem is I have so many implementations in this component. So it's better if I can do this with only css. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't think so. Try using slick js. That might do the trick.

Comment: The problem is, I've so many libraries and packages used in this component. That's why I cannot do that much change.. :(

Comment: Oh! What you can still try is to make the window scroll smoothly. See http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/auto-scrolling-page-using-jquery.php. It also has a demo http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/demo/demo_auto-scrolling-page-using-jquery.php. You will have to manage the scroll and not scroll functionality depending upon the height of the div. Maybe this will help you.